# Asp.Net: Change  value of Column in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a grid in asp.net which is populated from a table(actually a join),

There is a `column` named **EMPLOYEENAME**(which shows the name of the employees) and another column named **EMPLOYEEID**(showing the ID of the employees),

These two columns are related i.e employee 'Tom' would always have employee ID say '21'

currently I am editing the **employee name column** by using a drop down list ,

I need a code to automatically change the employee id appropriate to the employee name which is edited

i.e if I selected the employee name to 'TOM' the corresponding employee to automatically change to '21'

Comment: What about ID column? Is it also DropDownList? Share some code, so that we know the scenario.

Comment: no ID column is a read only type element

Comment: So, You can work on the dropdownlist selected index changed event and populate the read only element accordingly.

Comment: currently I have not yet appended the ID column,it was something I am planing to do,so showing the code may confuse the viewers

Comment: @ebad86 but I have hundreds of employees how would I match each on indexchange without using some query(I am weak in sql)

Comment: there is a attribute in asp dropdown "OnSelectedIndexChanged". u can write your logic of selection in that

Comment: If you are weak in SQL, then you can turn it into your strength by practice. And now is a good time. Cheers.

Comment: SQL should not be hard if you try. Form SQL queries in the SQL Studio or your SQL tool. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

As you are changing employee name using drop down list. So you can do this by setting autopostback=true for that drop down list and make event onSelectedIndexChanged.

On code page write code to fetch the employee id of the selected index of drop down and update it in your grid

On aspx page:

```
    AutoPastBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grid_selectedIndexchanged"
```

On code behind page:

```
protected void grid_selectedIndexchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{
/*Code to fetch data from Database for selected Employee */

}

Comment: I do this but I don't seem to get the id of the drop down since it is inside the grid view,so how can I get the value which is selcted in the drop down once it is changed?

Comment: On dropdown selectedindex change event use following code for that part:
[
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
int rowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
]
and you will get the index of the gridviewrow at which you want to change employeeid

Answer (score 0):

Review this link at MSDN @ [Gridview sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?ppud=4).

Review/study for Gridview SelectedIndexChanged event in C#, and the GridView properties in the XML/html file.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the EMPLOYEEID as the value of the ListItem. That way when you select an Item, you have the employee name and employeeid of the selected Item.

Can be achieved by databinding like this:

```
ddlEmpNames.DataSource = employees;
ddlEmpNames.DataTextField = "EMPLOYEENAME";
ddlEmpNames.DataValueField = "EMPLOYEEID";
ddlEmpNames.DataBind();
```

This would probably save you another database call too just to find the employee id from the name.